# how to create the login portlet using jsp in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: mysql, jsp, authentication, portlet, liferay

I am using Liferay 5.2.3 portal for my online healthcare project.
So i want to create the Login portlet for the user to log on.
Currently I am using the 7 cogs portlet Use the bruno@7cogs.com & bruno as password
but i want to create my portlet & use the username & password
So can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the default Login (or Sign in) portlet?

It's available, just add it to your page. It will show the currently logged in user if you're logged in, otherwise a form containing username/password.

Unrelated fyi: As you say you're running sevencogs on 5.2.3: Make sure to uninstall the sevencogs-hook before you delete or rename bruno. If that hook doesn't find bruno on startup it will create the full demo content again and delete your customizations in this process. This is well documented, but easily overseen. The behaviour is finally fixed in 6.0.5

Comment: No problem with default login but how to create the login with own user name & password & interact with MySql

Comment: ?? I guess I don't understand what you mean. Is it this (https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration) for mysql? Or Manage->Control Panel->Users->Add for a user with your own name? (add Administrator role if you want the same permissions as Bruno) Or rename Bruno, but beware the sevencogs-hook as I mentioned above.